# For loop to update group of UILabels

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to update eight separate `UILabel`s named `_letter1Label` through `_letter8Label` via a For loop, which is generating a random letter for each.

I'm not too sure how I can tell the for loop to update the label which corresponds to the loop iteration number. Here's my code so far:

```
- (void) generateRandomLetters {

    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        NSMutableString *letter = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", [ALPHABET characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [ALPHABET length]]];
        NSMutableString *labelFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_letter%dLabel", i];
        // Stuck here, need to update _letter(i)Label with letter..
    }
}
```

Just not too sure how to phrase it in the code! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be eight UILabel variables? Intuitivly I would put those eight values in an array of UILabels and iterate over the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep your labels in an array and then use the array's index to update them:

```
UILabel *labelToUpdate = [arrayOfLabels objectAtIndex:(i - 1)];
labelToUpdate.text = letter;
```

Comment: Okay, so that should work, but I can't access the `textLabel` property when referring to an element in the array, I assume it doesn't know it's a `UILabel`?

`letterLabels[i].textLabel.text = letter;`

Comment: Use a temporary variable like NikosM did (`labelToUpdate`) or cast it: `((UILabel *) letterLabels[i]).textLabel.text = letter`.

Comment: Never mind, I did it by changing the array to use `for UILabel* in letterLabelArray`.